# ansible progess of uri task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

After reading the docs it seems that ansible does not support do_until for multiple tasks in blocks and also an include_task. My use case is to do a post on a restful url and then get the status of that restful response and continue doing that. The restful response, for the sake of brevity has two attributes status and progess. It is easy enough to poll and retry on one attribute, but how to display the progess ?

```
- name: get command {{ command_id }} status 
  uri:
   url: "myrestfulurl/status/{{ command_id }}"
   method: GET
   user: "foo"
   password: "bar"
   body_format: json 
   validate_certs: no
   force_basic_auth: yes
   return_content: yes
   headers:
      X-Requested-By: foo
  register: rest_response
  until: rest_response.content | from_json |    json_query('Requests.request_status') == "IN_PROGRESS"
  retries: 3
```

the progess can be reported as following

```
progress: "{{ rest_response.content | from_json | json_query('Requests.progress_percent') }}"
```

How can i get that say in the name part of the task. Note that the registered response is not available the first time ?

for instance

```
- name: get command {{ command_id }} status {{ { rest_response.content is defined | ternary( ... ) }} ?
```

Attempted this as well

```
- set_fact:
   temp: "{\"Requests\" : {\"request_status\" : \"COMPLETED\" } }"
- debug:
   msg: "{{ temp | from_json | json_query('Requests.request_status')}}"

- name: get command {{ command_id }} status {{ rest_response.content | default(temp) | from_json | json_query('Requests.request_status') }}
```

which resulted in the following ; the values are not being resolved

```
FAILED - RETRYING: get command {{ command_id }} status {{ rest_response.content | default(temp) | from_json | json_query('Requests.request_status') }} (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: get command {{ command_id }} status {{ rest_response.content | default(temp) | from_json | json_query('Requests.request_status') }} (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: get command {{ command_id }} status {{ rest_response.content | default(temp) | from_json | json_query('Requests.request_status') }} (1 retries left).
```

note ; i have my in_progress and completely reversed for testing; hopefully that doesn't throw anyone off.

Comment: Add `| default(‘starting...’)` filter to the expression. Is that what you ask about? And are you sure you can get an updated name in the “retrying” output?

Comment: @techraf had tried this but none of the vars resolved but the loop iteration was correct .. will add the trial to the above question

Comment: So as you can see, the name is not templated in the retry message. You seem to request a feature. What’s the question for SO?

Comment: what can i do to achieve something similar ? the default of just waiting for the task to complete without any status progress may be okay , but having the progress printed would be better. attempted to use handlers with changed when to true and had a failed trial using async (fire and forget)

Comment: Let’s wait for answer(s) then. The only problem I see is that Ansible users with an experience significant enough to devise a workaround, use Ansible specifically for the purpose of **not having to stare** at the screen.